# Struts 1 map to static .xml file

Tags: java, jsp, static, mapping, struts

I'm trying to map the path /crossdomain.xml to some xml content (whether its contained in a jsp, xml, or any other files, I don't care). I'm running struts 1, and I've tried this:

```
<action path="/crossdomain.xml" type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction" parameter="/crossdomain.jsp">
</action>
```

This technique works if I replace the .xml in the path with .jsp (then I can access it as .jsp, but I need it to be a specific name).

I also tried the DefaultServlet answer from here: [Servlet for serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132052/servlet-for-serving-static-content) - apparently we don't have that catalina.DefaultServlet class. I tried using ActionServlet, without any luck.

Its super frustrating that the simple mapping I tried first fails without any errors or messaging. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to skip struts and go straight to Tomcat, a la:
http://ekawas.blogspot.com/2006/10/configuring-tomcat-to-serve-static.html

Comment: For some reason, I don't have the default servlet configured, and in trying to add it, it tells me that org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet doesn't exist (in fact org.apache.catalina doesn't even exist). 

I eventually had to copy catalina into our working lib directory and it worked!