# IS there any way to add files to a deployed web application on tomcat server

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat6

I'm working on a jsf2 web application and i need to upload files to a folder in my webcontent and keep them permanently, I used the technique that is mentioned in [JSF FileUpload Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817600/jsf-fileupload-directory) and i could upload to wtp... folder's subfolder, but as BlueC said it get lost when tomcat restarts, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the files in a Database using a BLOB field. It will depends of how you are implementing the persistence layer of your application but in the Java side usually you will implement this field as byte[]. So it will be comfortable for download or display the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the files to a certain directory/ default directory and then manually copy the files to a secured folder that is outside of the deployment directory and application server installation (yes you can do that).