# How to save uploaded file in JSF

Tags: jsf, file-upload, save

I am uploading a file in JSF. I am using Tomahawk's `<t:inputFileUpload>` for this, but the same question is applicable on e.g. PrimeFaces `<p:fileUpload>` and JSF 2.2 `<h:inputFile>`.

I have the below backing bean code:

```
private UploadedFile uploadedFile; // +getter+setter

public String save() throws IOException {
    String name = uploadedFile.getName();
    System.out.println("File name: " + name);

    String type = uploadedFile.getContentType();
    System.out.println("File type: " + type);

    long size = uploadedFile.getSize();
    System.out.println("File size: " + size);  

    InputStream stream = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) size];  
    stream.read(buffer, 0, (int) size);  
    stream.close();  
}
```

I am able to get the file name, type and size, but I am unable to save this file at a specific path. I can't figure out the proper way to save the uploaded file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: add more detail.post complete code

Comment: @Abin i edited with code, i am getting name of file but how can i upload it ot server , u know it?

Comment: your are using Myfaces..right?

Comment: yes, JSF1.1. And i want to store local file @server with perticular url

Comment: Actually i dont have error, but am using jsp page with <x:inputFileUpload> component. at Backbean am getting their name , size and type. but how can i store that file to perticular path(User Definable path or at server).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22382/discussion-between-rocco-and-abin)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `getInputStream()` method of the uploaded file represents the file content.

```
InputStream input = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
```

You need to copy it to a file. You should first prepare a folder on the local disk file system where the uploaded files should be stored. For example, `/path/to/uploads` (on Windows, that would be on the same disk as where the server runs). Note that you should **absolutely not** store the files in expanded WAR folder or even the IDE project's folder by using a hardcoded path or a web-relative path or `getRealPath()` for the reasons mentioned here [Uploaded image only available after refreshing the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page).

Then, you need to autogenerate the filename. Otherwise, when someone else uploads a file with coincidentally the same name later, it would be overwritten. You could use [`Files#createTempFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) facility to get an autogenerated filename.

```
Path folder = Paths.get("/path/to/uploads");
String filename = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(uploadedFile.getName()); 
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(uploadedFile.getName());
Path file = Files.createTempFile(folder, filename + "-", "." + extension);
```

The path to uploads could if necessary be parameterized based on one of several ways shown in this Q&A: [Recommended way to save uploaded files in a servlet application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application). The `FilenameUtils` is part of Apache Commons IO which you should already have in your classpath as it's a dependency of the Tomahawk file upload component.

Finally, just stream the uploaded file to that file (assuming Java 7):

```
try (InputStream input = uploadedFile.getInputStream()) {
    Files.copy(input, file, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}

System.out.println("Uploaded file successfully saved in " + file);
```

Then, to download it back, easiest would be to register `/path/to/uploads` as a new webapp context or a virtual host so that all those files are available by an URL. See also [Load images from outside of webapps / webcontext / deploy folder using <h:graphicImage> or <img> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-the-image-from-outside-of-webcontext-in-jsf).

Comment: thanx, And if I want to select multiple files at once, then what i need to prefer?

Comment: That's not possible with `<t:inputFileUpload>` which generates a plain old HTML4 `<input type="file">`. That's only possible with Flash or HTML5 `<input type="file" multiple="true">`. RichFaces and PrimeFaces offer such components. E.g. http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload&skin=blueSky and  http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf

Comment: Thanx, sorry for questioning more and more , but any other way using <t:inputFileUpload> ?

Comment: Just use multiple `<t:inputFileUpload>` components or use it in `<h:dataTable>` or `<t:dataList>` backed by a collection of `UploadedFile`.

Comment: @BalusC How can I save image in Maven `webapp/resources/imagens` ? I'm trying save an image in this folder but still can't do this works.

Comment: @BalusC I tried your example and I have an exception: `SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-89] image.beans.ImgUpload.upload null
 java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: D:\cmsdata\test-2264165946506714423.jpg` at the line `Files.copy(input, tempFile.toPath())`. When I go to the folder, there is a file `test-2264165946506714423.jpg`, but its size is `0KB`. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Alexander: when using PrimeFaces `<p:fileUpload>`, yes.

Comment: @BalusC why did you use  `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING` ? You said earlier in the answer that  `createTempFile()` would not allow duplicate names ence my confusion.

Comment: @Ced: because an empty temp file is physically created (and thus already exists) before writing. It works this way so the system can guarantee that no other temp file with coincidentally same name will be created by other thread between the creation and the writing.

Comment: it's "getInputstream()" with lowercased "s" & not "getInputStream()", please edit

Comment: @BalusC when its a temp file why do you need to give it a path? There is no such constructor reference as well anyway

Comment: @AliAdnan: the answer consists of text and code. Read both and not only the code.

Answer (score 1):

PrimeFaces uses two file upload decoder for uploading content of p:fileupload

1. NativeFileUploadDecoder
2. CommonsFileUploadDecoder

NativeFileUploadDecoder is the default upload decoder and it requires servlet container 3.0. So if your servlet container is less than 3 then it will not work with you. 
Also some application servers make a restriction on using multi-part content

So if you have a problem with the native upload decoder for any reason you have to use the other decoder which is "CommonsFileUploadDecoder"

CommonsFileUploadDecoder depends on Apache common lib 
so you have to put the **commons-fileupload and commons-io jars** in your class-path
the version depends on your primefaces version but 1.3 and 2.2 respectively works for me.

to use CommonsFileUploadDecoder you have to use filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

**wait the filter only will not work** because inside the filter it checks about the uploader if its not provided and it detect at least JSF 2.2 so it will bypass the request to the default decoder "Native" and then it will not work for your also

to force the filter to use the common decoder you have to put the following context param in your web.xml

```
<context-param>
<param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
   <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked-or-uploaded   

the answer for that post

Comment: Isn't all this in the PrimeFaces documentation?