# How to get the path of where my file is uploaded to and print it out

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I am using primefaces for file upload, i want to find the location of where this file is uploaded to and then print it out in the console, or the webpage, how can i do this

i know to call the location i use :

```
#{user.fileText}
```

but i want to know the exact path if possible, how would i do that ?

my upload filter :

```
public class UploadFilter implements Filter {
   private int sizeThreshold = -1;
   private String repositoryPath;

   public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
      repositoryPath = config.getInitParameter(
         "com.corejsf.UploadFilter.repositoryPath");
      try {
         String paramValue = config.getInitParameter(
            "com.corejsf.UploadFilter.sizeThreshold");
         if (paramValue != null) 
            sizeThreshold = Integer.parseInt(paramValue);
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
         ServletException servletEx = new ServletException();
         servletEx.initCause(ex);
         throw servletEx;
      }
   }

   public void destroy() {
   }

   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
      throws IOException, ServletException {

      if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
         return;
      }

      HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

      boolean isMultipartContent 
         = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(httpRequest);
      if (!isMultipartContent) {
         chain.doFilter(request, response);
         return;
      }

      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      if (sizeThreshold >= 0)
         factory.setSizeThreshold(sizeThreshold);
      if (repositoryPath != null) 
         factory.setRepository(new File(repositoryPath));
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

      try {
         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<FileItem> items 
            = (List<FileItem>) upload.parseRequest(httpRequest);
         final Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
         for (FileItem item : items) {
            String str = item.getString();
            if (item.isFormField())
               map.put(item.getFieldName(), new String[] { str });
            else
               httpRequest.setAttribute(item.getFieldName(), item);
         }

         chain.doFilter(new 
            HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpRequest) {
               public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
                  return map;
               }                   

               public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
                  Map<String, String[]> map = getParameterMap();
                  return (String[]) map.get(name);
               }
               public String getParameter(String name) {
                  String[] params = getParameterValues(name);
                  if (params == null) return null;
                  return params[0];
               }
               public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
                  Map<String, String[]> map = getParameterMap();
                  return Collections.enumeration(map.keySet());
               }
            }, response);
      } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
         ServletException servletEx = new ServletException();
         servletEx.initCause(ex);
         throw servletEx;
      }      
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `<p:fileUpload>`, you should not be homebrewing a custom filter at all. The custom filter as you've shown so far does not properly interact with `<p:fileUpload>` component at all. You should use the filter provided by PrimeFaces itself. Which one it is and how to use it is clearly explained in its [documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html). So you need among others exactly this filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

As to the save location, you've this fully in your own control. Just grab the file content in the bean (action)listener method by `UploadedFile#getInputStream()` and write it to the location of your choice.

You should not be interested in the location where PrimeFaces has "under the covers" stored it, it's namely a **temporary** location for the case the file is larger than the configured threshold buffer size (and thus will be automatically cleaned/deleted at intervals).

#### See also:

- [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked or UploadedFile is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked/8880083#8880083)
- [How to save uploaded file in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211843/how-to-save-uploaded-file/14214223#14214223)