# How do I make a directory outside the 'war' file : (Outside the project directory)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, directory, war

How do I make a directory outside the `war` file of my web-app ? Till now I have been making the directory like :

```
(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")).mkdir()
```

But I want to create the directory outside the `build` folder of my project ? How do I do this ?

(This is in-case a server doesn't unpack the war)

Comment: out of curiosity, why'd you want do this?

Comment: @eis incase a server doesn't unpack the war

Comment: @eis: to save uploaded files. See also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211843/how-to-save-uploaded-file/14214223#14214223 for the reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to create a class like:

```
class FolderMaker{
      private String base="/home/user/base/"; // should be configurable, but this is sample

      public boolean mkdir(name){
          return new File(base, name).mkdir();
      }
}
```

This class works like a simple Java SE class that creates a directory somewhere at disk.

Comment: I don't see the directory created ! But it is created for sure as `file.exists()` tell me.

Comment: isDirectory() returns? If we check dir it's better method.

Comment: Let us carry on this discussion here @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23583/discussion-between-koziolek-and-saplingpro

Comment: I didn't understand you. Can you please elaborate

Comment: I tried to make a file inside the directory but the same result. I do not understand the reason. I posted the code snippet in the same chat session