# save image file in specific directory jsf primefaces project

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, directory

I want to save byte[] file into a specific directory : 
I get it from this method :

```
public void setUploadedPicture(UploadedFile uploadedPicture)
{
    System.out.println("set : "+uploadedPicture.getFileName()+" size : "+uploadedPicture.getSize());        
    this.uploadedPicture = uploadedPicture;
}
```

and I access the byte[] with  :

```
uploadedPicture.getContents()
```

I tested this [link](http://www.java-examples.com/write-byte-array-file-using-fileoutputstream) but no result

how to save it into a specific directory either inside my project or outside

thank you

**************EDIT***********************
here is the code whic works but sometimes I have the error :

```
public void setUploadedPicture(UploadedFile uploadedPicture)
{
    System.out.println("set : "+uploadedPicture.getFileName()+" size : "+uploadedPicture.getSize());        
    this.uploadedPicture = uploadedPicture;

    InputStream inputStr = null;
    try {
        inputStr = uploadedPicture.getInputstream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //create destination File
    String destPath = "C:\\"+uploadedPicture.getFileName();
    File destFile = new File(destPath);

    //use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils to copy the File
    try {                    
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStr, destFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save uploaded file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14214223)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {  

    //get uploaded file from the event
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = (UploadedFile)event.getFile();

    //create an InputStream from the uploaded file
    InputStream inputStr = null;
    try {
        inputStr = uploadedFile.getInputstream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //log error
    }

    //create destination File
    String destPath = "your path here";
    File destFile = new File(destPath);

    //use org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils to copy the File
    try {                    
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStr, destFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //log error
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this portion of code(I m going to test it), I don'use this method because I use the simple mode of uploadfile then I work directly with byte[]  content

Comment: atbegin, the `getInputStream()` should also work just fine regardless of the upload mode. The only difference is that it doesn't put the entire file in server's memory and is therefore much more efficient.

Comment: @pantominas I tested your code, it works but the problem is sometimes I have this error when I submit : `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\upload__54ab5703_13da6c8fc2c__8000_00000016.tmp (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)`