# upload an image using primefaces and resize it using thumbnailator

Tags: image, jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

please let me know that how can i upload an image using primeface fileUpload.i want to store the uploaded image into a folder and also want to resize the image using thumbnailator .i have already tried the primeface fileupload but not getting.

`<p:fileUpload  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" auto="true" dragDropSupport="true" fileUploadListener="#{loginController.fileUploadHandler}" />`

```
public void fileUploadHandler(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
    UploadedFile file = event.getFile();
    InputStream inStream = file.getInputstream();
    Os.write("C:\\Users\\think again\\Desktop\\uploaded\\pic.jpg", inStream);
    Thumbnails.of(new File("C:\\Users\\think again\\Desktop\\uploaded").getAbsoluteFile()).size(100, 100).outputFormat("jpg").toFile("C:\\Users\\think again\\Desktop\\thumb");
}
```

but the file object contain a part item dont know what it is. will get the fileItem object inside the part.please help me to upload the image into  the correspondding location

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked?rq=1

Comment: @EvesMary : my backing bean is session scoped.instead of showing uploaded messages i need to store the image into a file

Answer (score 0):

how about this : [save image file in specific directory jsf primefaces project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638248/save-image-file-in-specific-directory-jsf-primefaces-project)
[PrimeFaces uploadFile: how can I save the uploaded image file to some directory in web app and retrieve it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817248/primefaces-uploadfile-how-can-i-save-the-uploaded-image-file-to-some-directory)
http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-upload-primefaces-32-under

and also did you try googling for a solution?