# p:fileUpload doesn't work using @Autowired bean annotation

Tags: spring, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I recived error when try upload file using **p:fileUpload**.
I tried maven clean and maven install for update dependeces.
I changed web.xml many times. I belive the problem is relationship with my anotation, **i m using @Autowired (Spring)** but i change it an donsen't work.
How i resolve this problem?

I m using:
**Primefaces 6.0**,
Java 8,
Spring Data,
Spring MVC

**my web xml:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

**JSF:**

```
<p:fileUpload id="fileDescAto" auto="true" multiple="false"
    invalidFileMessage="Tipo de Arquivo Inválido:"
    disabled="#{not empty searchDocumentoBean.descAtoArquivoFileName}"
    update="messagesDialog @this panelGroupFileDescription"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/" sizeLimit="10485760"
    invalidSizeMessage="Tamanho de arquivo excedido (10MB):"
    fileUploadListener="#{searchDocumentoBean.adicionaArquivoUpload}"
    label="Escolher Arquivo..." mode="advanced" />
```

**Bean:**

```
public void adicionaArquivoUpload(FileUploadEvent ev) {

        String[] name = ev.getFile().getFileName().split("\\\\");

        descAtoArquivo = ev.getFile().getContents();
        descAtoArquivoFileName = name[name.length-1];
    }

    public void removeArquivoUpload() {

        descAtoArquivo = null;
        descAtoArquivoFileName = null;
    }// GET AND SET OMITED
```

**Head annotation My bean:**

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
@ManagedBean(name = "searchDocumentoBean")
@URLMappings(mappings = {       
        @URLMapping(id ="searchDocumento", pattern = "/searchDocumento", viewId = "/resources/pages/documento/searchDocumento.jsf")
})
```

**ERROR CONSOLE WHEN I TRY USE FILE UPLOAD**

**javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException error obtained during the processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6: UIComponent-ClientId**

```
08:43:55,231 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) Error Rendering View[/resources/pages/documento/searchDocumento.xhtml]: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startMetadataIfNecessary(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:303) [primefaces-6.0.jar:6.0]
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startUpdate(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:142) [primefaces-6.0.jar:6.0]

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils.filterStylesheets(ResourceUtils.java:96) [primefaces-6.0.jar:6.0]
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startMetadataIfNecessary(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:287) [primefaces-6.0.jar:6.0]
    ... 49 more


08:43:55,246 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) JSF1073: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException obtido durante o processamento de RENDER_RESPONSE 6: UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=java.lang.NullPointerException
08:43:55,240 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-5) Error Rendering View[/resources/pages/documento/searchDocumento.xhtml]: javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**UPDATE 27/09/2017**
I recive error:
JBWEB000281: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown Servlet name Faces Servlet´

Where an error in my web.xml?

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
<filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>51200</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping> 

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>openEntityManager</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387993/spring-jsf-integration-how-to-inject-a-spring-component-service-in-jsf-managed (it is a duplicate imo)

Comment: So what about the info in the link I posted?

Comment: I have already visited this link, it does not solve my problem, I already tried to change the annotation (when applicable), but it did not solve my problem with p:fileUpload. I wonder if there is any other configuration needed. I've visited the Primefaces page to look for additional information, but the implementation of web.xml, bean, and jsf seem to match that presented on the sweb site.

Comment: I believe it's the dependency injection problem using 'Autowired', as this is the only difference I'm finding in my searches on the forums on the internet. I also tried the Primefaces forum, but I got no response if using 'Autowired' is associated with the malfunction of the primefaces component.

Comment: Regardless of all this, in the link I posted, it clearly states that using `@Component` AND `@ManagedBean` on a class at the same time is **wrong**

Comment: ok, it states `@component` but the 'issue' is the same

Comment: I believe I know the cause of the problem however I'm getting a Servlet error mapping specifies an unknown Servlet name Faces Servlet. please see UPDATE 27/09/2017. Thank You so much

Comment: Remove the faces servlet mapping as you do not seem to have (or need) one

Comment: i solve my problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659071/listener-method-in-pfileupload-is-never-invoked-in-primefaces

Comment: Thank You  Kukeltje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solve my problem:

[Listener method in p:fileUpload is never invoked in primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659071/listener-method-in-pfileupload-is-never-invoked-in-primefaces)

Besides That. 
i need especify location the Faces Servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

**javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet**

I needed especify resource primefaces depends for fileupload works fine>

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
        <param-value>commons</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

In some versions of primefaces it is not necessary to specify this configuration. I am currently using version 6.0, which believed that this specification was not necessary in web.xml because it is a newer version, but it was necessary.