# event.getFile().getFileName() is returning filename with complete path in JSF2.0 with PrimeFaces 3.5

Tags: windows, jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces v3.5 to upload the files in my windows machine using Firefox browser. `event.getFile().getFileName()` is returning filename with complete path which is causing problems further. Internally PrimeFaces is using Apache commons. I checked the [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getName%28%29) also but not helping me anymore.

To overcome with this issue, I modified the program a little bit like following manner-

```
        String fileName = event.getFile().getFileName();
        fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"));
```

But it's not robust and reliable. Any suggestions please?

Comment: fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1); for get name correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Commons IO offers [`FilenameUtils#getName()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getName%28java.lang.String%29) for the exact purpose.

```
String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(event.getFile().getFileName());
```

#### See also:

- [Commons FileUpload FAQ on the subject](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/faq.html#whole-path-from-IE)
- [How to save uploaded file in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211843/how-to-save-uploaded-file/14214223#14214223)

Comment: Hi BelusC.., It happened to me also and solved now, Thanks to you :)