# <p:filedownload> does not download the file

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, download

I am trying to download files (send them to browser) using primefaces filedownload. For some reason it does not send the file to the browser. The pop-up dialog I am using the p:filedownload in shows up when clicking on the button on my page. I already saw this: [p:fileDownload bean method is invoked but file download does not show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921023/pfiledownload-bean-method-is-invoked-but-file-download-does-not-show-up)
but the problem is that I need to set the file in the bean by calling the action when the user picks the fileName to download:

**test.xhtml**

```
<p:dialog>
    <p:dataTable var="currentAttachment" value="#{managerBean.attachmentsForPatient()}">
      <p:column>
        <p:commandLink value="#{currentAttachment.name}"  action="#{managerBean.downloadAttachment(currentAttachment)}">
          <p:fileDownload value="#{managerBean.file}" />  
        </p:commandLink>
      </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:dialog>
```

**managerBean.java**

```
public void downloadAttachment(Attachment attachment) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = ((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream(attachment.getContent().toString());  
    setFile(new DefaultStreamedContent(stream)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your web.xml for correct configuration.
Sample is posted here..

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also check that the following dependencies are added

> commons-fileupload*.jar,commons-io*.jar

This should help.

Comment: You're confusing "download" with "upload". Why this answer is accepted is totally beyond me.