# How can I add a client-side progress listener to a JSF 2.2 ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

I am trying to add a client side progress bar to  `JSF2.2 ajax`   requests. What I would ideally like to do is get the request header size and receive updates for the status of the   `POST.`

I do not know a lot about  `JS/JQuery`   but as far as I can tell,   `JQuery`     must initiate the request in order to achieve this([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery))

Is there a way to do this from the client-side only?

If this is not possible, what other (native) options do I have?

Thanks,

PS1. Although the main scope for this, is a file upload progress bar, I would like to be able to apply on the full request size.
PS2. I know there are a few libraries that offers this for free, but ATM I don't wan't to use any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research this is a little more complicated than it first appears.

**JSF and multiple files**

First of all, JSF 2.2 defines `<h:inputFile>` tag which is limited to a single file, i.e. it does not support HTML5 parameter `multiple=true`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837090/how-can-i-upload-multiple-files-with-jsf-2-2?rq=1) for more details. On the other hand, it is very easy to extend this tag to allow multiple files since the uploaded files are fetched from the `request`, so they are easily available.

**Where are the files parsed and persisted?**

All JSF requests are handled by the `FacesServlet`, which is annotated with Servlet's 3.1 tag `@MultipartConfig`. This annotation basically does all the heavy lifting of extracting and writing the uploaded files. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets011.htm) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet).

Although this is very handy and takes care of most things, it doesn't have a progress listener interface, which means that you will get the files (`Parts`) when they are fully uploaded. I don't see a way to actually intercept this is a clean way in order to implement a server-side progress bar.

**Server-side Vs Client-side progress listener**

In order to implement a server side progress listener, you will need somehow to handle files yourself and notify the user about the progress using `polling` or [WebSockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm).

For the client-side, you will need to either write a custom `POST` function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery) or use a library like this [this](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) to handle the `POST` as most browsers don't provide progress information. Basically, instead of using the browsers functionality to do a post (AFAIK) you handle the request yourself and hence you have control of the bytes transferred. The problem here is that `FacesServlet` expects a request which is formatted by the `jsf.js` functions and I do not see an easy way to intercept the `JS` request just for processing file upload.

**What are my options then?**

I would safely suggest using an existing library that offers this functionality. 
If you have the time and still want to DIY, I think that the best way to go is to write your own `FileUploadServlet` that 'understands' [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [XHR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) and use a `JQuery` plugin to initiate the upload and provide the client-side progress bar.

**Example**

I have finally decided to go with [JQuery/blueimp fileupload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). See **[this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456243/how-can-i-define-a-jax-rs-service-that-processes-multi-part-data-in-jee)** for details. Note, that this is not actually part of the normal JSF Flow, I developed a custom way for feeding the actual parts in my application.

PS. As I am new to this, don't read this answer as a definitive answer but as a starting point for your own research.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the [Malsup Form plugin for jQuery](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) is fairly simple and has good documentation and demo code (therefore fairly easy to use to Ajaxify a progress bar) if you want to go the jQuery (Javascript) route, which keeps things on the client side.

(Of course, other plugins also exist, like the [BlueImp file uploader plugin](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) which has *a lot* more possibilities, but may not be quite that easy to use.)

For a "JSF-only" solution, [BalusC recommends using a JSF component library like Primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098968/malsups-jquery-form-plugin-and-jsf-2-2) - which is probably a better option - it is recommended to read his comments and links he provides which explain reasoning behind the preference for one technology over the other.