# JSF upload file with both HTML5 D&D and input file

Tags: jsf, file-upload, drag-and-drop, jsf-2.2

In the widely well-discussed subject of file uploading, there is an aspect that I am missing. I have a JSF 2.2 application that uploads files via HTML5 exactly [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114087/html5-file-upload-to-java-servlet). It basically uses HTML5 apis to upload multiple files and then the JS calls a Servlet to write them on disk (the Servlet is called once per file, so no multiple Part treatment is necessary). **Now I want to enable `<input type=file>` in the same element**. This in isolation could be done exactly [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677397/how-to-upload-file-using-jsf-2-2-hinputfile-where-is-the-saved-file) (although perhaps the solution needs [some tweak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837090/how-can-i-upload-multiple-files-with-jsf-2-2) for multiple files, not sure if this latter information is obsolete).

My question is, I obviously want to code the file writing only once, not one in the Servlet and another in the Managed Bean:

- Should I do all writing in the Servlet? If so, how should I post the
  parts to the Servlet from the managed bean? (I am new to JSF)
- OR should I do all writing in the Managed bean, by calling the Managed Bean `save()` method from my D&D javascript? If
  so, I will change this line `xhr.open("POST", "uploadServlet", true)`
  to something else, but I am not sure how to make the call and pass
  the parts.

---

*As an aside note, now that JSF is freeing me from doing all sort of tedious stuff, I am not totally sure what the role of Servlets is. One more detail I should point is that, in future, I might want to mirror Web functionality in Web Services. Perhaps that will impact this answer and the way I should deal with JSF - meaning that I should do all functionality in Servlets and call them from both JSF and Web Services, instead of doing the functionality in the Managed Bean itself.*

---

**EDIT**

Still working on the problem. I am trying to get rid of the Servlet and use a method in the managed bean. However, I have no idea how I could submit the POST data to the managed bean. SO I have these in my **external JS file**:

```
xhr.open("POST", "uploadServlet, true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

And I should redirect it to the method. This is another way I could solve my problem but still some unknowns, how could I pass the POST to the method?