# Custom html attributes for HtmlInputFile

Tags: java, html, jsf

I create a HtmlInputFile like this:

```
HtmlInputFile input = new HtmlInputFile();
```

Which gives me HTML output like this:

```
<input id="id..." name="name..." type="file">
```

I would like to add the "multiple" attribute to this file upload, so that I get this output:

```
<input id="id..." name="name..." type="file" multiple>
```

HtmlInputFile supports various HTML attributes, but it lacks support for multiple. Is there any way to add it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use a passtrhough attribute

Comment: I did use passthrough attributes in JSF pages before, but I don't know how to use them when I'm generating the elements programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
input.getPassThroughAttributes(true).put("multiple", "true");
```

**See also:**

- [How can I upload multiple files with JSF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837090/how-can-i-upload-multiple-files-with-jsf-2-2)
- [Class UIComponent](https://static.javadoc.io/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.3.0/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getPassThroughAttributes--)

Comment: Oh wow, i was blind when going through the specification... Thank you very much!