# Best practice to save the uploaded images

Tags: java, jsf, save, mkdir

What is the best practice to save the uploaded images? Supposed that I have a form, each form has an ID. User can upload multiple images on a form. What I want to do is something like:

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |-- files
 |    |-- images
 |    |    |-- Form1
 |    |    |    `--Image1.jpg
 |    |    |    `--Image2.jpg
 |    |    |    `--...
 |    |    |-- Form2
 |    |    |    `--Image1.jpg
 |    |    |    `--Image2.jpg
 |    |    |    `--...
 :
```

`Form1` and `Form2` is a folder. The folder is automatically created on the server while the user submit the form. Is it a good practice to do that? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save uploaded file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211843/how-to-save-uploaded-file)

Comment: Do ab-so-lute-ly not store them in deploy folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything necessarily wrong with this approach, have you considered what would happen with multiple users?  Would they end up overriding each others image?  My advice there would be to use the UserID somewhere, either as a directory or appended onto the filename.

Normally, say if you were going to deploy in the cloud on something like AWS, you'd palm off all the folders onto their S3 technology rather than having them sit in your WebContent.

Comment: Nice.. Actually each form has its own ID, and it's separated on the different folder name based on the form's ID, so it would not end up overriding each others image. ;)

Answer (score 2):

An important best practice is to separate the application itself from the user data. So make sure to store the images on a filesystem outside your WebContent. An application redeploy will possibly delete the WebContent directory. It will also delete the user content which is not your intention.

Another best practice is to make the location of the files configurable. You don't want to hard-code it. Use a URL Resource for example.

The structure of your files directory makes sense. You probably want another user-specific directory under files.

Answer (score 0):

Are your waiting a huge amount of images? 
If yes, you should think about dividing images into subfolders, as file system become slow if there are a lot of files in one folder.

Comment: Now that all depends on the actual file system in question.

Comment: There should be more than one folder that contains images since I said that it should be saved on separated folder based on the form's ID. :)