# Write file into disk using JSF 2.2 inputFile

Tags: jsf, file-upload, file-io, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to upload an image file using h:inputFile tag and write it to disk.

My JSF code:

```java
<h:form id="fileUploadForm" enctype='multipart/form-data' prependId="false">
   <h:inputFile value="#{solicitacaoManagedBean.imagemCarregada}" />
   <br />
   <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-primary " value="Enviar" action="#{solicitacaoManagedBean.enviarImagem}" />
</h:form>
```

My ManagedBean:

```java
@Named(value = "solicitacaoManagedBean")
@SessionScoped
@MultipartConfig(location = "/home/rogerio/tmp/")
public class SolicitacaoManagedBean implements Serializable {

   private Part imagemCarregada;
```

(...)

```java
   public void enviarImagem() throws IOException {
      try {
         imagemCarregada.write("teste.jpg");
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
         System.out.println("Erro ao escrever: " + ioe.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

Supposedly, the method [write](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html#write%28java.lang.String%29) uploads item to disk and the IOException isn't throwed/catched too.

Comment: So is something not working?

Comment: Yes. The file is not written to disk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`@javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html) annotation is supposed to be placed on the class implementing `HttpServlet`, not on a backing bean class. Basically, that annotation has to be placed on the `FacesServlet` class, which is already done since JSF 2.2.

In other words, the `@MultipartConfig` annotation on your backing bean class is being ignored and has no effect and the file is actually not saved in the `location` you specified in the annotation. Instead, it's been saved in a path relative to the so-called *current working directory*, which is basically the "currently opened folder" at the moment `java.exe` is been executed. In case of Java web applications that's usually server's binary folder or so. You can track it down as below:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

You'll see your uploaded file there.

Moreover, even if the `@MultipartConfig` annotation did work, the `location` attribute does actually not represent the *permanent* file upload save location. Instead, it represents the *temporary* disk storage location for the case when the uploaded file size exceeds the available/configured memory space. You should never store uploaded files permanently at the location identified by `@MultipartConfig(location)`. You should always obtain the file content via `Part#getInputStream()` and write it to the desired permanent location provided by a new `File` or `Path` representing an absolute path.

Get rid of that whole `@MultipartConfig` annotation. It's not doing anything useful in a backing bean class. Just obtain the file content by `Part#getInputStream()` and copy it to the desired absolute path:

```
try (InputStream input = imagemCarregada.getInputStream()) {
    Files.copy(input, new File("/home/rogerio/tmp/teste.jpg").toPath());
}
```

#### See also

- [How to save uploaded file in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211843/how-to-save-uploaded-file-in-jsf)
- [Recommended way to save uploaded files in a servlet application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using a session scoped bean for this purpose is not ideal. Rather use a view or request scoped one. See also [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/) And, using `prependId="false"` is not recommended for other purposes than login forms tied to a login framework which doesn't support JSF-prepended ID in request parameter names. See also [UIForm with prependId="false" breaks <f:ajax render>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415230/jsf-namingcontainer-and-uiform-with-prependid/).

Comment: You should always write it out to the desired permanent location via _Part#write()_ >> do you mean Path#write() ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: No, `Part` is [`javax.servlet.http.Part`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html). See also my [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18664715/) on your current question.

Comment: I guess this : fileName - the name of the file to which the stream will be written. _The file is created relative to the location as specified in the MultipartConfig_ from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html#write%28java.lang.String%29) confused me

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. Now I have realized in which directory the method write() puts the file, but even specifying the absolute path, it doesn't work. The exception is thrown: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /srv/glassfish-4.0/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/jsp/identidadeWeb-war/home/rogerio/teste.jpg. I'll try another way.

Comment: Looks like a GF bug. In that case, stream `Part#getInputStream()` to a `FileOutputStream` yourself instead.

Comment: @rogerio_gentil: glassfish does not support absolute file paths in `Part.write()` apparently : see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738244/glassfish-part-write-no-absolute-paths-workaround)