# Casting multiform part to a file

Tags: java, html, jsf, zip, multipartform-data

I have a managed bean. An HTML/JSF page sends a zipped file as a Part. I need to extract the contents from it, but to do that I need it to be File. Is it possible to cast the Part to File like as follows, and then treat it like a normal zip file?

```
Part xmlFile;

public void myMethod()
{
File zippedFile = (File) getXmlFile();
....
}
```

If not, how would I go about doing so? I've looked on online but there seems to be very little information.

Comment: Check out this posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478154/write-file-into-disk-using-jsf-2-2-inputfile

Comment: Thank. Is there a way that I can convert it to a file in memory, without writing it to somewhere on the harddrive?

Comment: The Part class has a "getInputStream()" method.  You could use this to read and write into and storage medium you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a temporary file:

```
File aFile = File.createTempFile(PREFIX, SUFFIX);
```

And write the contents of your `Part` payload into that file:

```
try (InputStream input = part.getInputStream()) {
    Files.copy(input, aFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

You may also want to make use of `File`'s `delete()` or `deleteOnExit()` for cleaning up resources. Bear in mind that `deleteOnExit()` is only invoked when the JVM exits, which may not be what you want in your case.

Comment: Thanks. So if the file was a .zip before becoming a Part, I will have the same .zip again when I create a file from inputstream?

Comment: You will end-up with the exact same contents of the original .zip file.

Comment: File.createTempFile(PREFIX, SUFFIX); creates a file on disk.  @user3007194, what is final destination of Part - disk, database, post processing, other?

Comment: @GradyGCooper is right. It does indeed create a file in a temporary location in the filesys. I removed the reference to the 'memory-only' bit. However if a File object representation is a requirement, this is the closest you can get to it. Maybe we need to know what is meant by "treat it as a normal zip file".

Comment: If the app is to be run under a Linux environment, another idea is to make use of the "free" ramdisk `/dev/shm/`. In that case you can write files under that path and be assured that they remain memory-only.