# in primefaces 3 and jsf i upload the file but in destination place the image is not show

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

i used simple mode, glassfish 3.0 and primefaces 3.0

Backing Bean

private UploadedFile file;
private String destination="D:\temp\";

public void upload(FleUploadEvent event) {

```
    System.out.println("upload");
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Success! ", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        try  {
        copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile().getInputstream());
           } 
     catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
    System.out.println("uploaf finished");
```

public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
           try {

```
           // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination + fileName));

         int read = 0;
       byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
             out.write(bytes, 0, read);
         }

         in.close();
       out.flush();
         out.close();

    System.out.println("New file created!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
```

}

this is my jsf page

Comment: please help any body the image it not show in destination place

Comment: the following message is show not generated any exception or error only simple message "D:\tmp\C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ulcerimage.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)"

Comment: i am using same above code so please tell me in destination place the file have not been uploaded

Comment: Have your file field setter and getter methods?and may be help you followings link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211843/how-to-save-uploaded-file/14214223#14214223 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-files-uploaded-to-a-tomcat-servlet/18664715#18664715

Comment: sir i am using in jsf page  <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.upload}" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" sizeLimit="100000"/><br/> these code in above link i am unable set to destination place

Comment: Hosein Masbough sir for above link i had not got any help so please provide any solution change my code plese look the my jsf page code

Answer (score 0):

In your example "D:\tmp\" is followed by the full filename of the uploaded file, i.e. "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ulcerimage.jpg".
This is incorrect and leads to the error.
All what you need is to process uploaded filename: extract actual name without path information. 
You can use for example the following:

```
if (fileName.indexOf("/")>0){
  fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/"));
}
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination + fileName));
```

in copyFile method.

Comment: Gennady Nikolaev sir i am trying these above code  defined by you but i am not show the image in destination place

Comment: I am not sure I exactly understand what do you mean. Not show - you mean there is no image at destination? Some exceptions occur?

Comment: Gennady Nikolaev sir i am found my issue it is browser issue i am using IE11 browser it work fine in mozila and IE9,IE10 so thanks sir

Comment: these image show in destination place TEMP folder so but how to show these image in my sql database i am using mysql 5.0 please help any one

Comment: these image upload destination on IE10 browser but not upload in IE9 browser plese help i got stuck here