# Programmatically storing image files in JBoss

Tags: jsf, jboss, file-storage

I am developing a Java EE application for JBoss 6.1.0 which needs to programmatically store image files on disk.

How/where should I store image files on a JBoss server?

Comment: that's like saying "I have a Toyota, where should I go for lunch"? It really depends on what you want/need.

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness. Let me give you some more information. I am developing an e-commerce application using Java EE technologies such as JPA, JSF, Entity Beans, Stateless and SFSB, managed Beans and the Facade Design Pattern. The application sells car parts and I'd like to store the images of these car parts in the application server (in this case JBOSS 6.1.0) My questions are.1. Can I store the images of my product catalogue in the Application Server? If so, where? Thanks.

Comment: You used the word "JEE" in your question. May I please point you on this? https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/pages/JEE

Comment: Dear Balus C. I thought I HAD used Java EE, not JEE. Sorry but I cannot find any refernce to JEE in my text. But I totally agree with you . It is Java EE, not JEE. Lalin

Comment: Sorry, if I HAD used JEE but you subsequently corrected it. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `/standalone/data` folder for this, whose path is available via the `jboss.server.data.dir` system property.

```
File dataDir = new File(System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir"));
File yourFile = new File(dataDir, "filename.ext");
// ...
```

You are even allowed to create subfolders in there. Below example creates `/standalone/data/images`.

```
File imagesDir = new File(System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir"), "images");
imagesDir.mkdir();
File yourImageFile = new File(imagesDir, "image.png");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [JBoss directory structure](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/dirs.html)
- [JBoss system properties](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossProperties)
- [How to save uploaded file in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211843/how-to-save-uploaded-file/14214223#14214223)

Comment: Thank you! as always, you are a life saver Balus C!

Comment: A quick question, How do I reference this location from inside a JSF file. I want to show an images on the welcome page but I cannot get the image to come up.

Comment: Use the servlet approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-images-from-outside-of-webapps-webcontext-deploy-folder-using-hgraphi/ (this link is mentioned in bottom of "How to save uploaded file" link in above answer)

Comment: so, I store the images in the data folder in JBOSS. then use a servlet to access it? I am using JBOSS 6.1.0 as my AS I'm sorry BalusC but I am not quite clear as to how I should proceed here.

Comment: Just substitute `"/path/to/images"` part in the servlet example. Logical, right?

Comment: yes it does: so am I right here? pathToImages = "JBOSS6.1.0/server/default/data"

Comment: No .. The same as in above answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69908/discussion-between-lalin-pethiyagoda-and-balusc).