# Get file path of uploaded file from p:fileUpload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, path

I would like to upload one file at a time, get the path of each file and add it to a list. It would later be used to save them all in a permanent directory like `E:/myfile/...`.

I tried the following PrimeFaces component:

```
<p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadView.file}" mode="simple" />
```

However, I am unable to get the file path. How can I get it?

Comment: Just to be clear you want the source path on the client machine uploading the file?

Answer (score 3):

The enduser won't send you the full client side file path. Even then, if it did, how would you ever get the file contents by only the path? If it were possible, it would have been a huge security breach as basically anyone on the world would be able to unaskingly scrape files from anyone else's disk through the entire Internet.

Usually, only the filename is being sent and you should even not use exactly that filename to save the obtained content on disk in order to avoid files being overwritten in case (another) enduser coincidentally uploads a file with exactly same name. You should use it at most as metadata (e.g. to prefill the *Save As* filename in case enduser want to download it back at a later moment).

You should actually be interested in the actual file content sent to you in flavor of `InputStream` or `byte[]`, not the original client side path nor filename. The file content is sent **only once** and you should **immediately** read and write it to a more permanent location in the server side once the bean action method hits. Then, keep track of the (autogenerated/predefined!) filenames/paths of those saved files in some `List<String>` or `List<File>` in the view or perhaps the session scope.

#### See also:

- [How to save uploaded file in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211843/how-to-save-uploaded-file/14214223#14214223)