# Displaying image in JSF-based web application

Tags: java, jsf

I have a JSF application and I am trying to display an image that is sitting locally on another machine in the intranet:

```
<h:graphicImage id="image"
    url="\\myip\C\images\myimg.jpg">
</h:graphicImage>
```

`C` is a shared folder.

However it doesn't display it and when I look in the source it adds the localhost:8080 as post fix.

how can I deal with it?

When I write the URL with notepad - not as web application it works just fine!

Comment: possible duplicate of [load the image from outside of webcontext in jsf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-the-image-from-outside-of-webcontext-in-jsf)

Answer (score 2):

Use plain HTML - `<img src="...">`

Answer (score 1):

`url="file:///C:/images/myimg.jpg"`