# Displaying images in the form of a grid using JSF

Tags: image, jsf

I have a requirement where in I need to display images present in a directory as thumbnails in my JSP page. The page will be divided into a left panel and a right panel. Left panel, displaying the directories in the form of a tree structure. On click of a folder, images present in that particular folder need to be displayed as thumbnails in the form of a grid.

The tag `<h:graphicImage>` will not work in this case since my images are present outside the context root of my application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [load the image from outside of webcontext in jsf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-the-image-from-outside-of-webcontext-in-jsf)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a component library I would propose `p:dataGrid` of Primefaces library. An example is given in the [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datagrid.jsf).

You have to prepare the list of images in the backing bean.

Comment: As far I understand, the concrete problem is serving those images from outside the webapp, not the markup.