# Dump contents of a image file to the browser using JSP

Tags: jsp

How can I dump the contents of an image file on disk to the browser?

I tried this but the image is broken (broken image symbol in the browser).

```
<%@ include file="config.jsp" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
<%@ page contentType="image/png" %> 

<%
String fn = request.getParameter("f");

String filename = uploads_folder + fn;

File file = new File(filename);
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
int c;
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
    out.write(c);
}

%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JSP is meant as template for HTML/CSS/JS and other **text** based content. It's not meant as template for **binary** data like images. In essence, a JSP is the wrong tool for the job. You should be using a servlet class. Create a class which `extends HttpServlet` and do exactly the same job as you did in JSP in the `doGet()` method (although it can be made a bit more robust and efficient) and finally change the image URL to the servlet one instead of the JSP one.

#### See also:

- [Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java-w/1812356#1812356)
- [Load images from outside of webapps / webcontext / deploy folder using <h:graphicImage> or <img> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-the-image-from-outside-of-webcontext-in-jsf/4543951#4543951)

Answer (score 0):

It is neccessary to remove the line breaks outside of the JSP tags to not break the image.

```
<%@ include file="config.jsp" %><%@ page import="java.io.*" %><%@ page contentType="image/png" %><%

String fn = request.getParameter("f");

String filename = uploads_folder + fn;

File file = new File(filename);
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
int c;
while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
    out.write(c);
}

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider,
1) the data is not corrupt with whitespaces, use 'trimDirectiveWhitespaces' this page directive attribute to trim white spaces.
2) set the image content-type header

Thanks,
Ramesh