# Serve Images from a separate location in JSF1.1

Tags: java, jsf

We are having a lot of images which all exist in our webroot.
Is there a setting in JSF 1.1 which allows us to set location of 
image path.

Comment: I understand that you want to externalize images? If so, this is not related to JSF, but to webserver and webapp settings. This question is then a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-the-image-from-outside-of-webcontext-in-jsf

Comment: Yes you are right BalusC. Thanks for clearing up my doubt