# Retrieve the user response saved in a file in an app hosted on Cloudbees

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, cloudbees

I have hosted a Tomcat application on CloudBees which allows users to edit some XML and saves them. I need to download and save these files locally for my personal usage. However I could not find a way to do this. I tried the 'download source' option but it downloads the original files that I had uploaded and not the edited versions. However my application is able to access the edited versions (and so clearly everything is being saved all right). Getting these files back is extremely critical and necessary for me and is, in fact, the whole motive of this app. Kindly tell if there is some way to get back the files in CloudBees or any other free Java hosting site which would allow me to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear from your question how your app is currently dealing with these files, but I'll take a swing at providing some general info.

To support editing and downloading of files, your app design would need to address the following issues:

1. How do users edit/upload the changed XML?
2. Where does your app store the changed XML?
3. How does your app retrieve the edited XML and make it available for download?

For #1, you will need to provide an edit or upload interface in your app for manipulating the XML files.  I'm assuming this is something your app has already solved using a form of some kind.

For #2, you need to pick an approach for storing the files that is appropriate for app's needs and the runtime environment where your app will be deployed.  For instance, on CloudBees (or most other CLoud platforms), it's important to understand that the local filesystem of the app can be used for temporary storage, but it is not clustered and it will be wiped away each time the app is updated or restarted.  If these XML files need to be available forever, you will need to store them in a persistent location that is external to the application's runtime instance.  Most developers use databases (such as the CloudBees MySQL service) to store persistent data in this way.  In general, your app can store these files anywhere, but your app needs to manage how to store them, and how to retrieve them later.

For #3, to allow a user to download the changed files, you will need to implement your own mechanism for retrieving the file from its persistent location, and then send it back to the user's browser.  If you want something like right-click "Save As" to work, then your app will just need to support a URL that can display the edited XML file directly in the browser. If your app then provides a link to that URL, users can download it using RightClick+SaveAs. If you want the user to be able to click on a button/link and trigger a Save As dialog automatically, then you'd need to write a URL handler (Servlet) that serves the XML content up using a Content-Disposition header (see this [StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887165/setting-up-a-file-for-download-on-a-tomcat-server)).  This header will tell the browser that the file is supposed to be saved to disk, and allows you to provide a default file name.

Comment: For #1, yes that is already solved. For #2, I am actually saving the files on the local filesystem. The way it is implemented, the changed XML overwrites the original one. And my original question was about browsing the local filesystem of the app and saving the files directly from there. But I guess that is not an option here. So the only way left is to implement an interface for download.