# How to bind dynamic content using <p:media>?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, media, dynamic-content

I use the `<p:media>` to display static PDF content.

```
<p:media value="/resource/test.pdf" 
         width="100%" height="300px" player="pdf">  
</p:media>
```

How can I change it to display dynamic content?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like as in `<p:graphicImage>`, the `value` attribute can point to a bean property returning `StreamedContent`. This only requires a special getter method for the reasons which is explained in detail in the following answer on using `<p:graphicImage>` with a dynamic resource from a database: [Display dynamic image from database with p:graphicImage and StreamedContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage/12452144#12452144).

In your particular example, it would look like this:

```
<p:media value="#{mediaManager.stream}" width="100%" height="300px" player="pdf">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{bean.mediaId}" />
</p:media>
```

With

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class MediaManager {

    @EJB
    private MediaService service;

    public StreamedContent getStream() throws IOException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            // So, we're rendering the HTML. Return a stub StreamedContent so that it will generate right URL.
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        } else {
            // So, browser is requesting the media. Return a real StreamedContent with the media bytes.
            String id = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
            Media media = service.find(Long.valueOf(id));
            return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(media.getBytes()));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What if I keep my ManagedBean in @ViewScoped ?

Comment: It will fail: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994288 Always use a stateless bean with `<f:param>` for serving `StreamedContent`.