# <p:media display pdf from folder dynamically

Tags: pdf, jsf-2, primefaces, media

I have several pdf files saved in `...WebContent/Manuals/filename.pdf` that I am trying to display on my page. I am getting "Failed to Load PDF document" message in Chrome.

My Jsf:

`<p:media value="#{reviewBean.manual}" player="pdf" height="600px" width="1000px" />`

My @SessionScoped Bean:

> public StreamedContent getManual() throws IOException {
>
> ```
>       String type = "application/pdf";
>       String path = "";             
>       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
>
>
>       if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
>              return new DefaultStreamedContent();         
>       } else {          
>              path = "C:\\.....\\WebContent\\Manuals\\filename.pdf";
>              InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(path.getBytes());                        
>              return new DefaultStreamedContent(is, type);
>       }
> }
> ```

There is additional logic that i have left out for clarity which decides which pdf is displayed.

I have also tried the file path of `/Manuals/filename.pdf` as path

I tried following the below example:

[How to bind dynamic content using <p:media>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232339/how-to-bind-dynamic-pdf-content-using-pmedia)

In my case I do not need to retrieve a value using `<f:param`

Is my file path incorrect to display the image? Or am I building the Stream incorrectly? Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by merely returning the url as a `String`.

```
public String getManual() {     
    return user.getManuals().get(user.getLData().getDepart());              
}
```

Where the returned value is the file path of the pdf: `Manuals/filename.pdf`