# Why primefaces media dynamic doesn't work in view scope?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I use the media primefaces tag to present pdf's but if the bean is `@ViewScope` the stream is always null, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the desired JSF view state isn't available when the webbrowser is about to download the PDF in an entirely separate(!!) HTTP request. This is essentially exactly the same problem as with PrimeFaces `<p:graphicImage>` as answered in the following questions:

- [How to bind dynamic content using <p:media>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232339/how-to-bind-dynamic-pdf-content-using-pmedia)
- [Display dynamic image from database with p:graphicImage and StreamedContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage/12452144#12452144)

Basically, you need to pass an identifier of the desired media file as `<f:param>` and then create an entirely stateless managed bean which streams the desired `DefaultStreamedContent` depending on the current request phase ID and the supplied request parameter.

Comment: This works fine on Opra, Edge, Chrome BUT NOT ON FIREFOX 60.0.2 - `Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException`, why this is happening?

Comment: OK -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/43163279/9112160 Solved my first problem, now I have on Firefox that `context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE` is always the same "6", no entering on the else to charge the data :(

Comment: SOLVED -> https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-adobe-reader-view-pdf-files-firefox. Seams my firefox wasent prepare to view PDF, by default it wanted to download...