# Imposible to render StreamedContent into media using primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have tried thousands of alternatives trying to dispaly a pdf in web browser, this is part of my xhtml file:

```
<p:media value="registerController.showFile" width="300" height="450" player="pdf" />
```

And the controller:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class RegisterController implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
StreamedContent showFile;

public StreamedContent getShowFile() {

    Path pdfPath = Paths.get("path\\to\\image");
    byte[] pdf = null;

    try {
        pdf = Files.readAllBytes(pdfPath);
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdf);
    DefaultStreamedContent d = new DefaultStreamedContent(b, "application/pdf");
    return d;
}

public void setPintaArchivo(StreamedContent showFile) {
    this.showFile = showFile;
    }
}
```

In console's browser I get 404 error, here are some recomendations I have fallowed without success:

- [Unable to show PDF in p:media generated from streamed content in Primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484555/unable-to-show-pdf-in-pmedia-generated-from-streamed-content-in-primefaces),
- [How to bind dynamic content using <p:media>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232339/how-to-bind-dynamic-content-using-pmedia),
- [How to use p:graphicImage with StreamedContent within p:dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304967/how-to-use-pgraphicimage-with-streamedcontent-within-pdatatable)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have a full path (from resources folder) to already generated PDF file, you can load in your xhtml:

```
<object id="pdf_document" type="application/pdf" data="#{youBean.documentPath}?pfdrid_c=true" width="100%" height="500px">Your browser does not support this feature!</object>
```

Well, if you want to show a pdf content from byte stream returned by webservice, you can use primefaces-extensions's `documentViewer` component (that use PDF.js)

So you need, in your bean, load a byte stream and generate a `StreamedContent`:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class StreamBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private StreamedContent pdfContent;

    public void load() {
        try {
            // Simulate getting byte[] from external source, like webservice
            ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            InputStream inputStream = classloader.getResourceAsStream("file-sample.pdf");

            int byteReaded = 0;
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];

            while ((byteReaded = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1)
                buffer.write(data, 0, byteReaded);
            buffer.flush();
            byte[] pdfBytes = buffer.toByteArray();

            // Create the StreamedContent with readed pdf file
            pdfContent = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfBytes), "application/pdf");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Manage your exception here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public StreamedContent getPdfContent() {
        return pdfContent;
    }
}
```

**Important:** don't put `@PostConstruct` over load() method, it will be called in preRender event:

```
<ui:composition template="/your-template.xhtml" ... xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

    <ui:define name="pageBody">

        <f:metadata>
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{streamBean.load()}" />
        </f:metadata>                   

        <pe:documentViewer height="450" value="#{streamBean.pdfContent}" download="file-sample.pdf" />  

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

**Note:** be careful with the primefaces and primefaces-extensions versions, in this case i have used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That's right, never the less I need to consume a web service that returns an array of bytes in which pdf document is contained

Comment: @OliverSoria OK, but you need to specify the source in your question (is not a file). Hope that the answer update will be helpful to you