# Primefaces generate pdf and display on click of button

Tags: pdf, primefaces, commandlink

I have a requirement in which I have to generate a pdf and then on click of button "SHOW PDF",  I have to display on another window. 
I have been able to generate a pdf using IText and stored in my machine. I get a java.io.File object as my return value from my backend library which needs to be displayed on the screen. Can someone please guide me how to do this?

My xhtml file has the following code snippet:

```
<h:commandLink  action="PdfDisplayRedirect.xhtml" target="_blank">show PDF</h:commandLink>
```

my PdfDisplayRedirect.xhtml has the following code:

```
<p:media value="#{pdfGenerationAction.fileName}" width="100%" height="300px">  
Your browser can't display pdf, <h:outputLink value="InitialExamination33.pdf">click</h:outputLink> to download pdf instead.
```

My backing bean has the following code:

```
private File initialExaminationFile;
private generateFile(){
     this.initialExaminationFile = backendService.generateFile();
}
```

On clicking, I get a new window opened but the pdf file is not displayed.. Instead my screen from where I had invoked the command gets displayed there.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: which version of primefaces are you using ?

Comment: what is the browser you are using ?

Comment: Thanks for the response rags. I am using primefaces 3.4.2 and firefox as my browser

Comment: Just a guess: Maybe this `<p:media value="#{pdfGenerationAction.fileName}"` does not work. According to the primefaces showcase you would probably have to put the real path of the file.

Comment: Then which primefaces element tag should I use for display?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the response and no response.
I have found a solution myself which I would like to post so that those looking for a solution can use it.

My xhtml file included a commandlink

```
  <p:commandLink actionListener="#{pdfGenerationAction.generatePDF(initialExaminationEMRAction.patientID)}" oncomplete="window.open('PdfDisplayRedirect.xhtml')">broadcast Msg</p:commandLink>
```

My pdfGenerationAction bean file had the following lines of code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(this.initialExaminationFile);
    //System.out.println(file.exists() + "!!");
    //InputStream in = resource.openStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
            //Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this byte array output stream.
            System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
        }
        this.reportBytes = buf;
    }
```

I converted my file into bytearraystream and made it available in my session. Then I followed the suggestion given by BalusC at [Unable to show PDF in p:media generated from streamed content in Primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484555/unable-to-show-pdf-in-pmedia-generated-from-streamed-content-in-primefaces?rq=1)