# How to display pdf on JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi my code is as follows:

```
public StreamedContent getTempPdfFile() throws IOException {
    File testPdfFile = new File("D:\\AFC150_20180819_0103.pdf");
    streamedContent = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(testPdfFile), "application/pdf",
            "AFC150_20180819_0103.pdf");
    return streamedContent;
}
```

```html
<h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
    <p:media value="#{realReport.tempPdfFile}" player="pdf" width="1000px" height="300px">
        <f:param name="id"  />
    </p:media>
</h:panelGrid>
```

But the PDF file is not getting displayed on the page.

Comment: jsf:--- 
   <p:media value="#{realReport.tempPdfFile}" player="pdf" width="1000px" height="300px">
     <f:param name="id"  />
   </p:media>

Comment: Any errors in the log? Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484555/unable-to-show-pdf-in-pmedia-generated-from-streamed-content-in-primefaces

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sample, hope it helps, the code has the inline and attachment:

```
void sendBackPDFToClient()
{
        //File temp = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".pdf");
        File testPdfFile = new File("D:\AFC150_20180819_0103.pdf");
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

        ec.responseReset(); 
        ec.setResponseContentType("application/pdf"); 
        ec.setResponseContentLength((int)testPdfFile.length()); 

        //Inline
        //ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + testPdfFile.getName() + "\""); 

        //Attach for Browser
        ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + testPdfFile.getName() + "\""); 

        OutputStream output = ec.getResponseOutputStream();
        Files.copy(testPdfFile.toPath(), output);
        fc.responseComplete();


}
```

Comment: how do i invoke it on jsf?

Comment: I think create another link for example "getpdf.xhtml", put the function sendBackPDFToClient() in backbean, then create a frame  <iframe src="/yourapp/getpdf.xhtml" width="600" height="800" scrolling="no"></iframe>, (modify the Content-Disposition to Inline).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Document Viewer](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/documentviewer/basic.jsf) component of PrimeFaces Extensions?

I think its much easier to use than p:media and offers more features including ability to load it from a URL, a Stream, or a Resource.  That basic example shows you how to do it with all 3 types.

**JAVA:**

```
public StreamedContent getTempPdfFile() throws IOException {
     File testPdfFile = Paths.get("D:\\AFC150_20180819_0103.pdf").toFile();
     return new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(testPdfFile), "application/pdf",
                "AFC150_20180819_0103");
}
```

**XHTML:**

```
<pe:documentViewer height="500" width="1000" value="#{realReport.tempPdfFile}"/>
```

Comment: I tried using document viewer but i am getting this error:  Unexpected server response (403) while retrieving PDF

Comment: 403 is a security exception that means you don’t have permission to that url. Can you paste your. Sample code you used so I can see it?