# dynamic El expression evaluation in map

Tags: jsf, dictionary, el, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a bean which returns me map of key-value pairs ( String,String) . In my jsff, I need to access the map's value based on key which is a a dynamic El expression

```
<af:iterator id="i1" value="#{bindings.leaderBoardEntities.collectionModel}"
var="entity" rows="#{bindings.leaderBoardEntities.rangeSize}">

    <af:image id="i2" source="#  {pageFlowScope.ImagesBean.imageUrlPair[entity.displayName]}"
    shortDesc="user info" inlineStyle="width:50px;height:50px;"/>
</af:iterator>
```

I am unable to evalue the key for the map. 
I tried,

```
source="#{pageFlowScope.ImagesBean.imageUrlPair[entity.displayName]}
source="#{pageFlowScope.ImagesBean.imageUrlPair['#{entity.displayName}']}
source="#{pageFlowScope.ImagesBean.imageUrlPair['${entity.displayName}']}
source="#{pageFlowScope.ImagesBean.imageUrlPair[#{entity.displayName}]}--this is     syntactically wrong
```

However , this works

```
source="#{pageFlowScope.ImagesBean.imageUrlPair['Twitter']}
```

Kindly help me

Comment: What is the type of imageUrlPair?

Comment: The first line is valid syntax. The others are plain invalid syntax. I don't do ADF, but this problem suggests to have same grounds as explained for PrimeFaces `<p:graphicImage>` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage/12452144#12452144

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify <strike>JSF</strike> EL version, so here's a <strike>JSF2</strike> EL2.2 snippet that will work:

```
source="#{pageFlowScope.ImagesBean.imageUrlPair.get(entity.displayName)}
```

Comment: I am using JSF 1.2 , this #{pageFlowScope.ImagesBean.imageUrlPair.get(entity.displayName)} gives me a syntax error at get()

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your question if you iterating over a map or list , if it is a map then try the below code , if it is a list then it looks good to me.

```
  <af:image id="i2" source="#  {pageFlowScope.ImagesBean.imageUrlPair
[entity.value.displayName]}"
        shortDesc="user info" inlineStyle="width:50px;height:50px;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `source="#{pageFlowScope.ImagesBean.imageUrlPair[entity.dataProvider.displayName]}"`