# FileOutputStream to StreamedContent

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download, fileoutputstream

I'm making an Excel file with Apache POI, and I'm saving it into a `FileOutputStream`.

In XHTML, I want to download this file with [`<p:fileDownload>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml) but it needs a `StreamedContent` to work.

I want to know how to parse or cast my `FileOutputStream` into a `StreamedContent` to download it with PrimeFaces.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15970438/3365426

Comment: DefaultStreamedContent needs a FileInputStream, but i have a FileOutputStream already

Comment: Then look for ways to convert an outputstream to an inputstream

Comment: Hint: Try using an ByteArrayOutputStream... easy to get a byte[] and pass on to a ByteArrayInputstream

Comment: Why StreamedContent? Just write it to response directly. Which is most helpful in solving your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/q/9391838 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/7822758

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had to save my file into disk, and read it again later with a File type to save it into a StreamedContent.

The code:

```
HSSFWorkbook libro = new HSSFWorkbook();
FileOutputStream elFichero = new FileOutputStream("c:/Temp/MyExcel.xls");
        libro.write(elFichero);
        elFichero.close();
        libro.close();
        File fil = new File("c:/Temp/MyExcel.xls");
        StreamedContent excel = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(fil), new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(fil), "MyExcel.xls"));
```

later i could get my excel file by the `<p:commandButton>`.

Anyways i was looking for a way to try not to save it to disk before download...

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution without saving file to disk:

```
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook.write(outputStream);

    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
    StreamedContent streamedContent =  new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream, "application/xls", "output.xls");
```