# The method getCurrentPhaseId() is undefined for the type FacesContext

Tags: jsf

I have a problem with to show images into a `<p:dataTable>`. I'm following the BalusC's instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage) but when I try use `context.getCurrentPhaseId()` as follows,

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
    return new DefaultStreamedContent();
}
```

Then Eclipse shows the following compilation error on `context.getCurrentPhaseId()`:

> The method getCurrentPhaseId() is undefined for the type FacesContext

How is this caused and how can I solve it?
I'm using JSF 2 and Primefaces 2.2-snapshot.

Comment: Post your code with problems.

Comment: This might just be eclipse screwing with you (it happens to me more times than I can count. try commenting and uncommenting the offending line. You could also try to rebuild your project

Comment: I tried that, but the error still is there

Comment: Please mention the exact compilation error message.

Comment: At compilation moment, the console show me: The method getCurrentPhaseId() is undefined for the type FacesContext

Answer (score 0):

> *The method getCurrentPhaseId() is undefined for the type FacesContext*

That method was [introduced](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getCurrentPhaseId%28%29) in JSF 2.0. This compilation error thus suggests that you're actually using JSF 1.x or at least are compiling against JSF 1.x instead of JSF 2.x. As PrimeFaces 3.x is not compatible with JSF 1.x, this in turn suggests that your IDE project is at incorrectly referencing a JSF 1.x library in the build path and thus you're actually compiling against JSF 1.x.

Check the project's *Build Path* property and get rid of that JSF 1.x library. In fact, you should never have the need to fiddle around in project's *Build Path* property. Just setting the *Deployment Assembly* and/or *Targeted Runtime* right, and/or dropping the necessary JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder should really be all what you ever need to do as to library management.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, I have the javax.faces-2.2.1.jar and primefaces-2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar. Sorry, but I did wrong with the Primefaces version posted. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: As answered, remove JSF 1.x from build path.

Comment: But I don't know which jar I need delete, because I only have these .jar that I said and if I remove it the project doesn't work. Please, can you help me? I am very newer.

When I'd review into project facets I see that have JSF 2.1, this is the problem? because I can't change that property to JSF 2.2

By the way, thanks for your corrections in the post and excuse me for my english.