# Error when recording console image graphicImage Primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

as above solves the problem when loading an image from another controller using the component PrimeFaces "**graphicImage**" the problem I have now is when I burn the image to a local address, I generates a PrimeFaces mistake, but apparently not affect my current functionality.

The image loading makes the **setAddAttributes** method, the problem is that I notice is when I go to method to record **setSaveAttributes** what happens recorded smoothly my data, but leave me this exception in the console, I think it has to do that utility is SessionScoped manage (but it does not stand not recognize me and I manage generates a null).

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{mGraficoImagen.graphicImage}" cache="false" />
```

**Main Manage Controller:**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CMantConsultaProductosList {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{mGraficoImagen}")
    private MGraficoImagen mGraficoImagen;  

    private MProductoBean mantForm;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setViewAtributes() {
        MProductoBean mantForm = new MProductoBean();
        mantForm.setVnomImagen("fancoil-fn.png");
    }


    public void setAddAttributes(ActionEvent e) {
        StringBuilder archivoImagen = new StringBuilder();
        archivoImagen.append("C://images//");
        archivoImagen.append(mantForm.getVnombreImagen());      
        this.mGraficoImagen.setGraphicImage(new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(archivoImagen.toString()),
                                            "image/png",
                                             mantForm.getVnombreImagen()));
    }

    public void setSaveAttributes(ActionEvent e)  {
         .........

         iProductoService.grabarProducto(mantBean);
   }

    /* get and set */
}
```

**Util Manage:**

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "mGraficoImagen")
public class MGraficoImagen implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private StreamedContent graphicImage;

    /**
     * @return the graphicImage
     */
    public StreamedContent getGraphicImage() {
        return graphicImage;
    }

    /**
     * @param graphicImage the graphicImage to set
     */
    public void setGraphicImage(StreamedContent graphicImage) {
        this.graphicImage = graphicImage;
    }

}
```

**Error Console:**

```
feb 04, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.primefaces.application.resource.StreamedContentHandler handle
Grave: Error in streaming dynamic resource. Stream Closed
feb 04, 2015 5:11:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: Servlet.service() para servlet Faces_Servlet lanzó excepción
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.StreamedContentHandler.handle(StreamedContentHandler.java:78)
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:72)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:153)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.sgkyros.common.filter.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:243)
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.StreamedContentHandler.handle(StreamedContentHandler.java:68)
```

Comment: Apparently the error generates the second call me the manage @SessionScoped, then you should do in that case ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `InputStream` can be read only once (and then it will be closed, so that expensive file resources are freed up). Yet you appear to be assigning it as a property of a session scoped bean, which implies that it would be read multiple times.

This all is wrong. You should be using a stateless bean which creates and keeps the `StreamedContent` instance in **method local scope** inside the getter method. You should never assign it as a bean property and only create it when the browser actually requests the image. You can make it dynamic by passing around the image identifier (e.g. filename or DB PK) as a request parameter via a `<f:param>` nested in `<p:graphicImage>`.

[This was fleshed out and explained so many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20defaultstreamedcontent), among others in this answer: [Display dynamic image from database with p:graphicImage and StreamedContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage/12452144#12452144).

Comment: Thanks for help friend, I rejoiced the day.