# Using f:param inside o:graphicImage

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, omnifaces, graphicimage

The following used to work with `p:graphicImage` but not with `o:graphicImage`.

Problem: `data_id` is always null.

**xhtml:**

```
<p:dataScroller var="data"...
  <p:graphicImage  value="#{bean.imagel}" >
      <f:param name="data_id" value="#{data._id}" />
  </p:graphicImage>
```

**Bean:**

```
public InputStream getImage(){

    String dataId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext()
            .getRequestParameterMap()
            .get("data_id");
```

I also tried with `o:param` with the same result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<f:param>` inside `<p:graphicImage>` is a [PrimeFaces-specific trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-dynamic-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage-and-streamedcontent) to get the `StreamedContent` thing to work "as expected".

The `<o:graphicImage>` doesn't support it (neither does standard `<h:graphicImage>`). Just pass it as EL method argument the usual way. It ends up in more clean code.

```
<o:graphicImage value="#{bean.getImage(data.id)}" />
```

```
public InputStream getImage(Long dataId) {
    // ...
}
```

See also code examples in [documentation](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/graphicImage).

Comment: Thanks, by the way, I think it should be `value="#{bean.getImage(data.id)}"` instead of `bean.image` ?

Comment: Indeed, copypaste mistake, sorry!