# Display p:fileupload image in p:graphicImage preview without saving it

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, preview, graphicimage

I am using PrimeFaces 5.3 `<p:fileUpload>` to upload a PNG image and I would like to show a preview of it in `<p:graphicImage>` before saving in database.

Here's a MCVE:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload value="#{bean.uploadedFile}" mode="simple" />
    <p:graphicImage value="#{bean.image}" />
    <p:commandButton action="#{bean.preview}" ajax="false" value="Preview" />
</h:form>
```

```
private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
    return uploadedFile;
}

public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
    this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
}

public void preview() {
    // NOOP for now.
}

public StreamedContent getImage() {
    if (uploadedFile == null) {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(); 
    } else {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(uploadedFile.getContents()), "image/png"); 
    }
}
```

No error occurring on the backing bean, and the image won't be load and display at front-end. The client mentions that the image returned a 404 not found error.

Comment: You say the upload works so how is this issue [tag:file-upload] related and not [tag:graphic-image]

Comment: because the `byte[]` source is come from the upload content, so i had obtained the upload content `byte[]`, but when i use the upload content to be display on the web page, its not gonna display and saying that the resource is not found

Comment: So you mean that if you manually put a byte[] in the database, not via the file-upload, it works?

Comment: Sorry sir, you misunderstood my question, I have not tried database yet, as it is not working via the file-upload

Comment: The flow are suppose to be like "Upload Image -> Preview Image -> Store into Database" in expecting, but for now I cannot Preview Image because the content from Image Upload cannot be display

Comment: @BalusC please review my updated question, the issue is exactly same

Comment: I did not save the uploaded file, I stored in variable and reuse as soon as I submitting to display for preview

Comment: yes correct, i wonder it is an "Unsaved" uploaded file, as I had assign into a variable for temporary use, only perform permanent saving after a final confirmation for user.

Comment: So I must perform storing the file somewhere else in the file system or database? there are no way to display the image without saving?

Comment: sure there is, in a longer scoped bean... But would you want to?

Comment: longer scoped bean? Pardon me, I am not well understanding in scoped bean concept, please guide me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is two-fold. It failed because the uploaded file contents is request scoped and because the image is requested in a different HTTP request. To better understand the inner working, carefully read the answers on following closely related Q&A:

- [Display dynamic image from database with p:graphicImage and StreamedContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-dynamic-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage-and-streamedcontent)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/)

To solve the first problem, you need to read the uploaded file contents **immediately** in the action method associated with the form submit. In your specific case, that would look like:

```
private UploadedFile uploadedFile;
private byte[] fileContents;

public void preview() {
    fileContents = uploadedFile.getContents();
}

// ...
```

To solve the second problem, your best bet is to use the data URI scheme. This makes it possible to render the image directly in the very same response and therefore you can safely use a `@ViewScoped` bean without facing "context not active" issues or saving the `byte[]` in session or disk in order to enable serving the image in a different request. [Browser support on data URI scheme](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri) is currently pretty good. Replace the entire `<p:graphicImage>` with below:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty bean.uploadedFile}">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,#{bean.imageContentsAsBase64}" />
</ui:fragment>
```

```
public String getImageContentsAsBase64() {
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageContents);
}
```

Note: I assume that Java 8 is available to you as [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) was only introduced in that version. In case you're using an older Java version, use [`DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageContents)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printBase64Binary(byte[])) instead.

In case you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), you can also just use its [`<o:graphicImage>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/graphicImage) component instead which is on contrary to `<p:graphicImage>` capable of directly referencing a `byte[]` and `InputStream` bean property and rendering a data URI.

```
<o:graphicImage value="#{bean.imageContents}" dataURI="true" rendered="#{not empty bean.imageContents}">
```

Comment: Thank you @BalusC the issue now has been totally verified and had resolved according to your solution approach, very thanks to your effort

Comment: @BalusC why in my case didn't works? Repository https://github.com/zaknafein83/uploadimage-primefaces-tutorial.git

When i start, io get a nullpointer exception on method to convert byte[] content into String (Base64).  If i add a null pointer control, i never get the preview of the image

Comment: is there a way, when the user choose the file, the image is displayed?