# Loading byte arrays into p:graphicImages

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a Image loaded from a database as a `byte[]`. 
Does anyone have a Bean example of how to turn it into a `StreamedContent` object and use it in the `<p:graphicImage value="#{bean.image}"/>`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Named
public class ImageBean {
    private StreamedContent image;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        image = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray)); // your byte array
    } 
    // setter and getter for image omitted
}
```

Then you call `#{imageBean.image}` in your xhtml page on a `p:graphicImage` element

Comment: Thanks for answering in a clear and objective way. I had a feeling that I'd done this before, apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should read [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12452144/3736575) for an example on how a bean for serving [StreamedContent](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.0/org/primefaces/model/StreamedContent.html) should look like.

For your special origin there also exists a [ByteArrayContent](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/6.0/) which is furthermore serializable.

To use

```xml
<p:graphicImage value="#{bean.image}" />
```

your bean will have to look something like this:

```java
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Bean {

  private byte[] imageLoadedFromDatabase;

  // code to set (or load) image from database
  ... 

  public StreamedContent getImage() {
    if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    } else {
        return new ByteArrayContent(imageLoadedFromDatabase);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I read that answer you suggest before and unfortunately it did not work for me (actually the omnifaces bit worked, but I got some other problems with it afterwards, so I'm back with primefaces).