# Dynamic images with StreamedContent

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, graphicimage

I have implemented two StreamedContent beans to dynamic load a graphic image, following the solution found 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-dynamic-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage-and-streamedcontent)

1) With the first one I display images in a contentFlow (EVERYTHING OK)

```
<p:contentFlow value="#{imageBean.images}" var="image">
           <p:graphicImage value="#{imageStreamer.fileContent}" styleClass="content" cache="false">
                  <f:param name="index" value="#{image.index}"/>
            </p:graphicImage>
</p:contentFlow>
```

2) With the second one I try to display images using a foreach (or repeat):

```
 <c:forEach items="#{imageBean.images}" var="item" varStatus="varStatus">
          <p:graphicImage value="#{imageStreamer.fileContent}" cache="false">
                            <f:param name="index" value="#{varStatus.index}" />
          </p:graphicImage>
</c:forEach>
```

This doesn't work. The check (`context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE`) is always true.

If I change the scope of the Bean to `RequestScoped` than it works! I'm confused... can someone help me?

Managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ImageStreamer{

      public ImageStreamer(){}

      public StreamedContent getFileContent(){
        List<Link> links = this.getLinkItems();
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String linkIndex = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("index");

        if(fc.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE){
          return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        }else{

          int parsedIndex = Integer.parseInt(linkIndex);
          Link ql = links.get(parsedIndex);
          return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(ql.getBytes()), "image/png");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide your managed bean code?

Comment: I have added it to the question

Comment: `If I change the scope of the Bean to RequestScoped than it works` . Do you mean changing `ImageStreamer`'s scope here? This shouldn't be a problem at all for your application.

Comment: Sorry, I had something wrong... now it's working... I really don't know why...