# Image from DB isn't displayed on JSF page

Tags: primefaces

I use MySql db with images in blob and try to display them on my JSF page using PrimeFaces galleria. On my page I see this galleria, but images aren't displayed. I see only small green icons in a corner of every image. I get this problem only using DB. If my images are in my file system, everything will be OK. Can someone explain why I can't see images from DB? I wrote this code:

**Galleria:**

```
<p:galleria value="#{imagesView.images}" var="image" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="250" showCaption="true">
        <p:graphicImage value="#{image}" alt="Image Description" title="Title"/>
</p:galleria>
```

**ImagesView:**

```
@ManagedBean
public class ImagesView {

    private List<StreamedContent> images;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        images = new ArrayList<>();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        int itemId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("item_id"));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            images.add(new GraphicImage().getImageFromDB(i, itemId)); //It's so simple because I need it just for test and that's all
        }
    }

    public List<StreamedContent> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
}
```

**GraphicImage:**

```
@RequestScoped
class GraphicImage implements Serializable {

    StreamedContent getImageFromDB(int id, int itemId) {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        } else {
            byte[] image = DBUtils.getImage(id, itemId);
            return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(image), "image/jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

**DBUtils method:**

```
public static byte[] getImage(int id, int itemId) {
        byte[] image = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try (Connection connection = DataBase.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT content FROM images WHERE id = ? AND item_id = ?")) {
            statement.setInt(1, id);
            statement.setInt(2, itemId);
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            resultSet.next();
            image = resultSet.getBytes("content");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display dynamic image from database with p:graphicImage and StreamedContent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-dynamic-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage-and-streamedcontent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not how a `p:graphicImage` works. You're trying to display an image using a byte array while this tag requires an URL to the image (or a StreamedContent).

```
<p:graphicImage value="img/myImg.png" />
```

Now, you have 2 options (at least)

1. either create an image from your byte array (image data) and store
   it somewhere where it's accessible by your web application. The value attribute should still contain an URL rather than a byte array.
2. don't store images in your DB, but rather store an image name (or
       path to a image on the server ) (e.g. your DB will just constain
       img001.png, img002 png etc and you know they're all inside, say, the img
       folder on your server. Then, all you have to do is change the image URL.

   ```
   <p:graphicImage value=#{imgUrl} />
   ```

Option 2 is actually recommended especially for large images, but even when your images are not large this method has the advantage of not having to convert images (byte arrays) to files.

In your HTML, this will be rendered as

```
<img src="img/img001.png" >
```