# primefaces streamedContent and p:media does not update contents

Tags: jsf, primefaces

**Hello everyone,**

I'm trying to show different pdfs from dataTable but that's impossible

**My goal:** Show the pdf associated with the item in the table

**The problem:** When I click for the first time on a pdf that I want to show, it actually renders, but when I want to see another pdf it always shows the first one that I select.

If I start everything for the first time, and if I click in the last item, shown that:

[image]

If I want to show the third pdf, it shows:

[image]

and the third pdf has a different document (I am very sure of that)

I have read this [Display dynamic image from database with p:graphicImage and StreamedContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-dynamic-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage-and-streamedcontent/12452144#12452144)
, but I have not been able to find the solution, because I use a dialog and I could not use a f param correctly

**My Code XHTML:**

```
        <p:dataTable var="documento" value="#{docController.obtenerDocumentos()}" 
                     ...
                     filteredValue="#{docController.filteredValue}"
                     >

            ......
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Acciones"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:form>
                    <center>
**here I send the document to be shown in the bean**
                        <p:commandButton styleClass="ui-priority-primary" icon="fa fas fa-eye" update=":visualizacion" action="#{visualizarDocumento.verDocumento(documento)}" value="Ver documento" onstart="PF('cargando').show()"  onsuccess="PF('cargando').hide()"/>                                                
                        <br/>
                        <p:commandButton styleClass="ui-priority-primary" icon="fa fas fa-align-justify" action="#{docController.respuestaDocumento(documento)}" value="Ver respuestas"/>
                    </center>
                </h:form>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:dialog widgetVar="visualizarPDF" modal="true">
            <h:form id="visualizacion" >
                <p:media value="#{visualizarDocumento.streamedContent}" width="750" height="560" player="pdf" />
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
```

**BEAN**

```
@Named(value = "visualizarDocumento")
@Stateless
public class VisualizarDocumentoController {
    private StreamedContent streamedContent;
    InformacionDocumento doc;

    public void verDocumento(InformacionDocumento documento) { 
        doc=documento;
        byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(doc.getArchivo().getBase64());
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(decode);
        streamedContent = new DefaultStreamedContent(bis, "application/pdf");
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        requestContext.update(":visualizacion");
        requestContext.execute("PF('visualizarPDF').show()");
    }

    public StreamedContent getStreamedContent() {
        return streamedContent;
    }

    public void setStreamedContent(StreamedContent streamedContent) {
        this.streamedContent = streamedContent;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs because the web client has cached the stream and only refresh it after some time.

Add attribute cache="false" in p:media element to force web client to reload the stream every time you refresh "visualizarPDF".

Comment: This solution can also be applied to a <p:graphicImage>.