# How to refresh DB data in Application ScopedBean?

Tags: java, refresh, javabeans, application-scope

From [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-dynamic-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage-and-streamedcontent/12452144) I learned that my page which contains a `StreamedContend` has to be related to an `ApplicationScoped bean`, but its has the consequence that if I modify some data (saved in DB) in an other page, the image build with the `StreamedContent` will not take these modifications into account

*Bean*

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ImgBean{
    @EJB
    private EJUser ejuser;

    @PostConstuct
    private void init(){
        // init some lists and objects from DB
    }

    public StreamedContent getChart(){
        //build and return 
    }
}
```

---

*xhtml*

```
<p:graphicImage id="chart" value="#{imgBean.chart}" >
</p:graphicImage>
```

My problem is, how to refresh the data inside this Bean, but not everytime it `get` the chart, because I can stay on this page and refresh the chart a lot of times, but more like when i open the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `metadata` can achieve this purpose, `onload` method here will be called each time the page is open

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{bean.onload}" />
</f:metadata>
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ImgBean{
    @EJB
    private EJUser ejuser;

    @PostConstuct
    private void init(){
        // init some lists and objects from DB
    }

    private void onload(){
        init();        
    }

    public StreamedContent getChart(){
        //build and return 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use `@ViewScoped` instead.

Annother option would be to add a method that updates the underying data and may be triggerd by a `commandButton`.

Comment: As states the post I linked to, ViewScoped cannot be used here, If it were I wouldn't be asking

Comment: then the second approach to add a button that triggers the reload woud fit.