# how to render a birt chart to a stream (png, svg)

Tags: java, render, birt, outputstream

i am able to render my charts to different file types:

```
 dRenderer = ce.getRenderer("dv.SVG");//or dv.PNG
 dRenderer.setProperty(IDeviceRenderer.FILE_IDENTIFIER, path);
```

but how to get the binary data as a stream? the charts will most likely be end in some one's browser. so a file on disk i relativly useless.

(it would be stupid to save many charts on disk before reading them again, wouldn't it?)

**Answer in short:**

it is possible to give an Outputstream instead of a path string as "FILE_IDENTIFIER" (works with both "dv.SVG" and "dv.PNG")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SVG set the file identifier to the output stream and make sure to set the content type(response.setContentType( "image/svg+xml" );

```
    try
    {   
        RunTimeContext rtc = new RunTimeContext( );
        rtc.setULocale( ULocale.getDefault( ) );

        Generator gr = Generator.instance( );
        GeneratedChartState gcs = null;
        Bounds bo = BoundsImpl.create( 0, 0, 600, 400 );
        gcs = gr.build( idr.getDisplayServer( ), chart, bo, null, rtc, null );

        idr.setProperty( IDeviceRenderer.FILE_IDENTIFIER, out ); 
        idr.setProperty(
                IDeviceRenderer.UPDATE_NOTIFIER,
                new EmptyUpdateNotifier( chart, gcs.getChartModel( ) ) );

        gr.render( idr, gcs );
    }
```

[See this link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/909746/#msg_909746)

Comment: thx for complete example on eclipse forum. to give a outputstream as "FILE_IDENTIFIER" is simple but not obvious ;-).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know BIRT that much, but what you can do is set the renderer to render the image in a `BufferedImage` and get the bytes out of it.

```
dRenderer = ce.getRenderer("dv.PNG");

BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(size1, size2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)img.getGraphics();
dRenderer.setProperty(IDeviceRenderer.GRAPHICS_CONTEXT, g2d);
dRenderer.setProperty(IDeviceRenderer.CACHED_IMAGE, img);

// render

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
baos.flush();
byte[] imgBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

I don't think it will work for SVG though. But there seems to be a newer API to generate reports with BIRT, where you can passe Rendering Options to the renderer, especially an option to set an `OutputStream`, you will give it a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and there you go, you can serve it to your web client.

Comment: thx the png part is solved. but i cant find something to get svg as an object (String or something else)? I can't find anything in "IDeviceRenderer" - do you have further tips?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return your PNG directly to a browser, you need some kind of server-side machinery. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204287/how-to-return-a-png-image-from-jersey-rest-service-method-to-the-browser) you can see how to do it with a REST service