# Give image from database a link with jersey

Tags: java, html, rest, hyperlink, jersey

I am self teaching myself how to write rest services. I insert the input stream into my database and now I want to use the image a user might upload. I would like to give the image to its own link... How do I go about doing that with jersey? I cant not find a tutorial online.. I'm stumped on how to go about this.

Here is how i'm getting the image.. it post to my database with a few functions I did not include.

```
@Path("/submitinfo" )
public class SubmitName {   

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public String post(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormParam("first") String name) {
        Connection con = connection();

        postName(con, name);
        postPhoto(con, uploadedInputStream);
        return name;            
    }
}
```

Comment: how about this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204287/how-to-return-a-png-image-from-jersey-rest-service-method-to-the-browser

Comment: Thank you! That way will certainly work however is that frowned upon to do it that way?