# Is there a common way to download all types of files in jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to download office files,pdf files,image files,zip files,dll files,exe files based on the user selection.So, I want to download these file types from jsp page.

This is jsp code snippt:

```
<% 
String filename = "Sample1.docx"; 
String filepath = "e:\\temp\\"; 
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM"); 
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\""); 

java.io.FileInputStream fileInputStream = new java.io.FileInputStream(filepath + filename);

int i; 
while ((i=fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
    out.write(i); 
} 
fileInputStream.close();
%>
```

But it raising some error when downloading office files, images files.When i open the downloaded files it says "The File may be Corrupted".

Is there any common way to download all types of files in jsp?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-the-image-from-outside-of-webcontext-in-jsf/4543951#4543951

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, there are some issues when downloading files from different browsers. My example takes care the handling needed in MSIE and Mozilla type of browsers

```
public HttpServletResponse getFile (HttpServletRequest request ,HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, .......){
          HttpServletResponse response = httpServletResponse;
          InputStream in =/*HERE YOU READ YOUR FILE AS BinaryStream*/

          String filename = "";
          String agent = request.getHeader("USER-AGENT");
          if (agent != null && agent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1)
          {
            filename = URLEncoder.encode(/*THIS IS THE FILENAME SHOWN TO THE USER*/, "UTF8");
            response.setContentType("application/x-download");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + filename);
          }
          else if ( agent != null && agent.indexOf("Mozilla") != -1)
          {
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            filename = MimeUtility.encodeText(/*THIS IS THE FILENAME SHOWN TO THE USER*/, "UTF8", "B");
            response.setContentType("application/force-download");
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
          }


          BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
          byte by[] = new byte[32768];
          int index = in.read(by, 0, 32768);
          while (index != -1) {
              out.write(by, 0, index);
              index = in.read(by, 0, 32768);
          }
          out.flush();

          return response;
}
```

check this out

**UPDATED**

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the `out` variable in a JSP is a [JspWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspWriter.html), which is a character stream and so your binary files get altered. You would be much better off using a servlet directly for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with JSP's "Out.write", which is not capable of writing byte stream...

Replaced jsp file with servlet...

The code snippet is:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String filename = (String) request.getAttribute("fileName");
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment;filename="+filename);

        File file = new File(filename);
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] outputByte = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        //copy binary contect to output stream
        while(fileIn.read(outputByte, 0, (int)file.length()) != -1)
        {
        out.write(outputByte, 0, (int)file.length());
        }
     }
```

Now U can download all types of files....