# How to offer download of local PDF file in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, download

I have JBoss running as application server and somewhere on my HD there is a PDF file, that gets created when the user clicks on a specific action. Let's say the file is here: `C:/PDF/doonot/10.07.2012/doonot.pdf`. How can I offer this file as download? I already did it for a CSV file, but I don't know how to do it with PDF.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How did you do it for the CSV file?

Comment: are you using some kind of web application to offer the file for downloading or are you using JBoss like an ftp server?

Comment: No, the file is just stored on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i wrote on [Is there a common way to download all types of files in jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702683/is-there-a-common-way-to-download-all-types-of-files-in-jsp/10703377#10703377)

you can use something like this:

```
public HttpServletResponse getFile (HttpServletRequest request ,HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, .......){
          HttpServletResponse response = httpServletResponse;
          InputStream in =/*HERE YOU READ YOUR FILE AS BinaryStream*/

          String filename = "";
          String agent = request.getHeader("USER-AGENT");
          if (agent != null && agent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1)
          {
            filename = URLEncoder.encode(/*THIS IS THE FILENAME SHOWN TO THE USER*/, "UTF8");
            response.setContentType("application/x-download");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + filename);
          }
          else if ( agent != null && agent.indexOf("Mozilla") != -1)
          {
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            filename = MimeUtility.encodeText(/*THIS IS THE FILENAME SHOWN TO THE USER*/, "UTF8", "B");
            response.setContentType("application/force-download");
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
          }


          BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
          byte by[] = new byte[32768];
          int index = in.read(by, 0, 32768);
          while (index != -1) {
              out.write(by, 0, index);
              index = in.read(by, 0, 32768);
          }
          out.flush();

          return response;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Dont forget that you can use the InputStream  as this:

```
// read local file into InputStream
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("c:\\SOMEFILE.xml");
```

or you can use it even like this

```
//read from database
Blob blob = rs.getBlob(1);
InputStream in = blob.getBinaryStream();
```

Comment: Can you explain how that works: "HERE YOU READ YOUR FILE AS BinaryStream"?

Comment: Thx. But it is not a BinaryStream, is it?

Comment: It doesn't work. The file is offered as download, but it is empty. :(

Comment: The problem was of course: `InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));`

Comment: @dooonot  are you sure it is not working as is? It shouldn't have any problem

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write a servlet wich read the pdf and write it to the response output stream.

Exemple here : http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/servlet/668-how-write-servlet-sends-file-user-download.html

Comment: Good input, gonna try this one! Thx

Comment: "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired"...

Comment: you probably add unwanted data at the beginning or at the end of the file, or not flush, or whatever. Try to download a simple text file with your servlet to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Gustav is right. Java doesn't discriminate amongst file types. A file is a file, if you did it for csv, it should also work for pdf.

Comment: no it doesn't. It says the file is damaged and could not be repaired.