# Why HTML Image Tag does not work in file protocol?

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsf

I have image Tag in XHTML(JSF) Page, the source for the image is reference to local image file i.e (c:\test.png), and my application server is JBOSS 7.1, **the problem is the image dose not display I used the file protocol** but still it dose not display my tag as the following.

```
<img width="200" height="200" src="file:///C:/images/003.jpg" />
```

But in my java code I can access the image by code, and if I write spectated HTML PAGE i.e (No application server no JSF page pure html) the

```
<img width="200" height="200" src="file:///C:/images/003.jpg" />
```

Works in pure HTML.

Any idea why is not work.

Comment: Check whether this helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-the-image-from-outside-of-webcontext-in-jsf

Comment: i make a folder reference to my application server but still the image dose not displayed , but i can access it by a code

Comment: use h:graphicimage component for displaying image in jsf

Answer (score 0):

Three times /// ? Or try c://images/003.jpg without file://

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your image in the resource folder and use the jsf-command

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-graphicimage-example/