# How to set an image with an absolute path to a h:graphicImage?

Tags: jsf, absolute-path, graphicimage

I have a web application that creates QR codes and store them in **C:\QR**

I sometimes need to get those images and put them in a **h:graphicImage**.

How to get those images stored in **C:\QR** and put them in a **h:graphicImage**?

And also how to get them from their **server path** (I have some of them stored there)?

I have this code but it only works for the images in the "imagenes" directory...

```
<h:graphicImage value="/imagenes/marcas-cadillac.png" width="115" height="58"/>
```

I am using NetBeans 8.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [load the image from outside of webcontext in jsf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-the-image-from-outside-of-webcontext-in-jsf)

Comment: @Templar hey I checked that and I want to use option 2. But I dont know where is glassfish-web.xml in my NetBeans project. Do You know where is it or how to add it? Should I add it in web.xml?

Comment: It is in `web/web-inf` you can probably add it just to your `web.xml`.

Comment: @Templar I added this in the xml: `<context-param>
        <param-name>alternatedocroot_1</param-name>
        <param-value>from=/QR/* dir=C:</param-value>
    </context-param>` and in the view: `<h:graphicImage value="/QR/1.png" />` but it didnt worked. The image path is: **C:\QR\1.png** what an I doing wrong? How should the path be written?