# How to add external resources to dynamic web project eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, war

I'm creating a dynamic web project in eclipse using jsps and java servlets, however I want to add some external files to be edited using the app. Where do I put them such that I can open them from my app and save an edited version - and finally provide a link for a download of the edited file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Where do I put them*

Nobody cares. Really. As long as it's not in the deploy folder, of course.

If your concrete problem is avoiding to hardcode the exact external location in Java source code, just provide it as VM argument, environment variable, properties file setting, or whatever externally configurable. For detail, see also [Recommended way to save uploaded files in a servlet application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-files-uploaded-to-a-tomcat-servlet/).

And/or if your concrete problem is serving those files back to the web, just either tell the server to publish the external location into the web as well, or create a servlet which reads from the external location and writes to the response. For detail, see also [Load images from outside of webapps / webcontext / deploy folder using <h:graphicImage> or <img> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-images-from-outside-of-webapps-webcontext-deploy-folder-using-hgraphi/).