# Using JSF for <a href="myPicture.png" .../>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el, graphicimage

I have the following code:

```
 <div id="links" class="links">
     <ui:repeat var="storageAttachment"
        value="#{gallerySlideshowController.selectedStorageAttachmentList}"
        varStatus="status">

                 <a
                    href="https://farm9.static.flickr.com/8839/27742500683_1da5eca775_b.jpg"
                    title="Banana"> <p:graphicImage
                       title="#{storageAttachment.name}" cache="true"
                       value="#{galleryPictureThumbnailRequestController.pictureThumbnail}"
                       rendered="#{galleryPictureThumbnailRequestController.pictureThumbnail != null}">
                       <f:param name="id" value="#{storageAttachment.uniqueId}" />
                    </p:graphicImage>
                 </a>
     </ui:repeat>
```

How can I replace the link in `<a
href="https://farm9.static.flickr.com/8839/27742500683_1da5eca775_b.jpg"` to my picture path?
I have stored the path on my local PC for every storageAttachment item. For example:
Object1: storageAttachment.path = C:/mypicture.png

So I need something like:
href="#{storageAttachment.path}"
-> But this is also not correct because I got http://C:/mypicture.png

How can I do this?
Thank you for every help.

Comment: `storageAttachment.path` is returning the wrong value, simple as that. It should not return a full path name, only the part that you want to use as the `href`.

Comment: If your application is used locally only, you could use the `file` protocol.

Comment: No, it´s not only locally.... How can I change the galleryPictureThumbnailRequestController.pictureThumbnail (it´s from the type public StreamedContent getPictureThumbnail() to a link?

Answer (score 0):

Your `PictureThumnailRequestcontroller.pictureThumbnail` is `StreamedContend`, there are no  `href` methods or getHref or anything like that but, you can get the image's `InpuStream` *via* `pictureThumbnail.getStream()`.  I suppose what your trying to achieve is to render the image but bigger?

1. So maybe try a simple Servlet to [render the image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4543951/2940051)
2. Use [Omnifaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/graphicImage) to render with better ease.

Comment: I try to create a component like this: https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/blob/master/README.md    But it seems I need the URL of the picture in href or do you have any other ideas?