# JSF streaming a image from computer as my fav icon

Tags: jsf, icons, favicon

I want to have a fav icon in JSF which is streaming from the local computer. This means the fav icon is not directly in the project folder included.
How can I do this? Can anybody help me?

I need the following:
My User will upload the images / favicon to the server.
Currently I have the favicon in the "resource" folder from my webapp.
But I would like that the images (the path of the image is stored in the database) is showing as my favicon.
This means the favicon is phyiscal stored at the server and not in the webapp.
I did this same with other pictures with primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/graphicImage.xhtml but I don´t know how can I do this with favicons?

Thank you for every help.

Comment: Why? Weird requirement. Users can in most os'es already change the icon of a bookmarked site

Comment: Who will do this? Do you change the icon from facebook e.g.????? My requirement is to store the fav icon not directly in the project folder because it should be changable everytime

Comment: No, I don't change the favicon of any site, but especially not in the way you required. Want it changable? Then store it in the database with the userprofile, simple technically the most sound/safe etc

Comment: Maybe there this some confusions:
I need the following:
My User will upload the images / favicon to the server.
Currently I have the favicon in the "resource" folder from my webapp.
But I would like that the images (the path of the image is stored in the database) is showing as my favicon.
This means the favicon is phyiscal stored at the server and not in the webapp.
I did this same with other pictures with primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/graphicImage.xhtml but I don´t know how can I do this with favicons?

Comment: Dear BalusC, yes, I know and implement this already for "normal" pictures but how can I do this for FavIcons?
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
If I use for example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/graphicImage.xhtml than I got a <img in the html output.
The question is how can I do this for a FavIcon?

Comment: Which one would you  recommend? Please let me know the number

Comment: @BalusC: Why did you remove your post? Which one of them can I use from your link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543936/load-images-from-outside-of-webapps-webcontext-deploy-folder-using-hgraphi

Comment: Just take a good look at them, think... and make yourchoice. Should not be to hard

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge: you can't.

The best thing to do is just include the favicon in the project directory.

Comment: I want to have the FAV icon dynamic. This means evey user can define their own fav icon

Comment: include them all in the directory then use javascript to allow users to define them.

Comment: Is there no possibility to use for example something like: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/graphicImage.xhtml